How do I copy files from my PC to the root directory of the "On My iPad" section of the Files app using a USB cable?
I would like to copy files from my Windows PC to the root directory of the "On My iPad" section of the Files app via USB cable. I am using Windows 11 and iPadOS 15.8.2. What I mean by "root directory" is the files you get in the topmost directory when you simply select "On My iPad" in the left column of the Files app, under the "Locations" heading. I can't seem to find the place in iTunes to copy it, but I did find the place to browse files from other apps. I tried 3uTools as well, but I'm not sure where to go.

There isn't a way to directly copy files to the root directory of the Files app, but there is a workaround.
If you are copying multiple files and/or folders, it may be easier to zip them first.
PC to iPad

On the iPad, download Brave, Chrome or Firefox (web browsers) from the Apple App Store. You only need one of them. (My favourite is Brave since it has built-in ad blocking, but that is off topic for this question.)
Connect the iPad to the Windows computer with iTunes using a USB cable and trust the computer when prompted.
In iTunes, select the device in the top bar. Then, in the left column, click on "File Sharing" (it may also be called "Apps" in older iTunes versions).
Under "File Sharing", you will see a list of apps. Select one of the aforementioned web browsers, and under "[appName] Documents" in the right column, drag files you want to copy there or click the "Add..." button (may also be called "Add File...") to browse for files to add manually.
On the iPad, open the Files app, then go to "On My iPad" under "Locations" in the left column. You will see folders with app icons on them. Open the folder with the name of the browser app and the icon of the browser app you chose earlier. (The app folder will not be visible if an app has no files. Do not empty out the folder, otherwise you won't be able to see it.)
You will see your copied files in the folder. Now, you can move them anywhere you like in the Files app by dragging them around, including the root directory of "On My iPad".

iPad to PC

Follow steps 1-3 above.
Open the Files app on the iPad, go to "On My iPad", then open the app folder of the browser app you installed as described above. If you do not see the app folder of the browser app you downloaded, that means the app folder is empty. To solve this problem, create a dummy text file donotdelete.txt with whatever text you want inside, follow the steps above to copy the text file to your desired browser app, and do not delete it.
In the Files app, drag the files you want to copy to your PC to the app folder of the browser app you installed.
Under "File Sharing" in iTunes, select the browser app where you copied the files, then simply drag them out of iTunes into your desired folder. You can also select them and click on the "Save..." button (also called "Save To..." in older versions).

Alternative
You can also use LocalSend, a free and open-source cross platform app to share files across your local network.
